# how to optimize mysql query with inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, clause

```
select id from customer_details where store_client_id = 2 
And
    id  NOT IN (select customer_detail_id from  orders 
        where store_client_id = 2 and total_spent > 100 GROUP BY customer_detail_id ) 
Or
    id IN (select tcd.id from property_details as pd, customer_details as tcd 
        where pd.store_client_id = 2 and pd.customer_detail_id = tcd.customer_id and pd.property_key = 'Accepts Marketing' 
        and pd.property_value = 'no') 
And 
    id IN (select customer_detail_id from orders 
        where store_client_id = 2 GROUP BY customer_detail_id HAVING count(customer_detail_id) > 0 ) 
Or
    id IN (select tor.customer_detail_id from ordered_products as top, orders as tor 
        where tor.id = top.order_id and tor.store_client_id = 2 
        GROUP BY tor.customer_detail_id having sum(top.price) = 1)`
```

I have this mysql query with inner join so when it run in mysql server it slow down what is the issue cant find.
 
But after 4-5 minutes it return 15 000 records. This records is not an issue may be.
In some tutorial suggest to use Inner join, Left join,...
But I don't know how to convert this query in Join clause.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First of all please read [relational model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model) and [optimizing select statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-optimization.html).